# Missing lib 'libruby.so.1.9' error while ruby installation in Ubuntu 12.4 using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install ruby using rvm on a remote server through terminal. 
I am following this link 
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

But at the install step I get the following error. I tried to look for the issue over net but couldn't resolve it. Please help me here.

**$ rvm install 1.9.3**

```
https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p286.tar.bz2 - #configure<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #download<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extract<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #validate<br>
**Libraries missing for ruby-1.9.3-p286: libruby.so.1.9. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries** <br>
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.<br>
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286 (already extracted)
Patch cflags was already applied.<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configuring<br>
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #compiling<br>
Write failed: Broken pipe
```

Comment: $ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --disable-binary
Solved!! But don't know how this "--disable-binary" part is gonna effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to update rvm first, this problem is supposed to be fixed already:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

if you still see it report problems/errors here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: I moved .rvm folder from $HOME folder to a custom location by following steps at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302680/936494 and suddenly when tried to view the ruby version, after executing "rvm use 1.9.3 --default", I encountered following error: "ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Searching for solution to fix this following @mpapis advice to run "rvm reinstall 1.9.3" worked for me smoothly.Thanks.