# How to change rvm install location?

Tags: linux, rvm

Currently I have rvm installed under `/home/john/.rvm`

How do move rvm to the location `/opt/local/rvm` ?

I tried to use the rvmrc file to take care of this (according to the rvm document here: https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/ ) but no luck, I found a `rvmrc` file under `/etc/`

Is there any step by step instruction I could follow?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Figure out myself by doing some research online, hope this can help someone out:

Suppose you want to move from `home/username/.rvm` to `/opt/local/rvm`

1. Update you `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` to:

   > ```
   > if [ -s "$HOME/.rvmrc" ]; then
   >     source "$HOME/.rvmrc"
   > fi # to have $rvm_path defined if set
   > if [ -s "${rvm_path-$HOME/.rvm}/scripts/rvm" ]; then
   >     source "${rvm_path-$HOME/.rvm}/scripts/rvm"
   > fi
   > ```
2. find your `.rvmrc` under `$HOME/.rvmrc`, if not found, create one and put this line in it:

   `export rvm_path=/opt/local/rvm`
3. move your file to the new location : `mv $HOME/.rvm/* /opt/local/rvm`
4. execute `rvm repair all` and `rvm reload`

And you are good to go!

Comment: I kept having permissions issues using this approach, issues which eventually led to me having to nuke the old rvm location and reinstall back into my home directory from scratch. YMMV, but make sure you backup everything first, just in case.

Comment: have you tried to just move an create a symbolic link on home ?

Answer (score 13):

You can do

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --path /path/you/want/rvm/installed/to
```