# Need help understanding this bash variable: "${rvm_path-$HOME/.rvm}/scripts/rvm"

Tags: bash, variables

I was reading the answer here: 
[How to change rvm install location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282509/how-to-change-rvm-install-location)

it keeps referencing the below variable:

```
"${rvm_path-$HOME/.rvm}/scripts/rvm"
```

I know that I have $rvm_path and $HOME set, but I don't understand what the whole excerpt means.

Comment: See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parameter expansion.

If a variable named `rvm_path` exists, it is expanded. Otherwise, `$HOME/.rvm` is used instead. Regardless, `/scripts/rvm` is appended to the result.