# define rvm installation directory

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

My $HOME directory is full and I only have space on /data/ directory on the VM. I am installing RVM offline using the directions given on https://rvm.io/rvm/offline
Is there a way to define RVM installation directory while offline install?

Note: I already found a method [to move RVM installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282509/how-to-change-rvm-install-location). However I am looking for way to define installation directory while a fresh install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am too impatient. Found it.

```
./install --path='/data/' --auto-dotfiles
```